# apply frame from external file in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

Is there any way to apply a frame from external module to a root window.
i have 2 files:
in
**a.py**
which has the line `self.root = root()` and i have a function in a class which imports **b.py**
and
in
**b.py**
i have a class and instantiated a Frame to display in root window
 `self.frame = Frame(root)`.
There is no error but frame widget is not showing up in the root window.
I tried changing `root` to `self.root` in **b.py** file

For Example:

```
#file 'a'
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root()
        root.title('Hello')
        self.b = None
    def boo(self):
        import b
        self.b = b.A()
Root.boo()

and

#file 'b'
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack()
    def __a_meth__(self):
        Button(self.frame, text = 'YES')
        Button.pack()
```

What changes need to be done?

Comment: Definitely there is error because `self.root` is undefined in `A.__init__()`.

Comment: Thanks, I figure it out. The mistake was i assigned  the call to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would pass in anything needed:

```
#file 'a'
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root()
        self.root.title('Hello')
        self.b = None
    def boo(self):
        import b
        self.b = b.A(self.root) # pass the root object in
        self.b.__a_meth__() # don't forget to call this if you want to see anything
Root.boo()
```

---

```
#file 'b'
class A:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack()
    def __a_meth__(self):
        Button(self.frame, text = 'YES')
        Button.pack()
```

Comment: I tried this, but the frame isn't packing in the root window.

Comment: You'll need to show a [mcve] for us to help with that.

Comment: Sorry, but thanks, i figured it out. The mistake was i didn't pass the object and assigned it to a variable.